# SQL for Fuzzy Match Deduplication

Tags: sql, duplicates, fuzzy-comparison

Table A has records with duplicate entities with subtle string variations. There is no unique key that would uniquely identify an entity. Field "ID" identifies record inside the table, but not an entity itself.

```
    TABLE A
    --------------
    ID;SomeString
    1;something1
    2;something2
    3;something3
```

By using fuzzy match software, the table A is fuzzy matched against itself, in order to detect duplicate records. That's how lookup Table B is created, which has two columns: ID1 and ID2, representing IDs of matched records from Table A.

```
    TABLE B
    ---------
    ID1;ID2
    1;2
    1;3
    2;1
    2;3
    3;1
    3;2
```

The result of deduplication would be to delete records 2 and 3 from table A, so that only first record is retained.

```
    TABLE A
    --------------
    ID;SomeString
    1;something1
```

Is there a way to perform such fuzzy match deduplication of Table A through SQL, by using Table B as fuzzy match lookup table of identified duplicate records?
To clarify, I'm not asking for a way to do the fuzzy match or identify duplicates, it's already done and results are in the table B. I'm asking how to perform deletion of duplicates (and retaining one record per identified duplicate records group), according to already identified duplicate record pairs (multiple duplicate record pairs per same entity).

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to actually do the fuzzy match in SQL (maybe, but there are better tools for that), or if there's a way to use the _results_ of your fuzzy match (in Table B) to handle the deletes (yes, easily)?

Comment: If the similar values follow a somewhat consistent pattern, you could use the `LIKE` operator with some wildcard (`%`) values to find similar values. One issue with your table B is that you have mirrored values, such as 1;2 and 2;1. If you cleaned it up to remove such duplicates, you could then delete rows in Table A based on values of ID2 in Table B.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You need to define what exactly constitutes a fuzzy match. Is it sharing 90% of characters, equal consecutive characters exceed 90% of string length, non-numeric characters match, etc... I'm no etymologist, but I bet "fuzzy" logic is called that to intentionally imply ambiguity. If you are going to do this in SQL your goal needs to be unambiguous.

Comment: I'm not asking for a way to do the fuzzy match, it's already done and results are in the table B. I'm asking for a way to perform deletions of duplciates in table A according to identified duplicates (results in Table B). What DBMS is used is really not relevant, my question was general about SQL.

Comment: @zlatko Which DBMS might be relevant because they each implement slightly different functions, so there could be a function that would handle it well in one DBMS that is not implemented in another. In this case I believe it's solvable with a fairly simple `CASE` statement, but that may not always be the case, even if it seems like a general SQL question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem I see is that your table of fuzzy matches contains duplicate pairs with the order of the IDs reversed. This means you have rows to say both 2 is a duplicate of 1, and 1 is a duplicate of 2. If you deleted all the rows based on the ID2 column of Table B, you'd just end up deleting all the rows in Table A.

You can solve this problem with a select statement that rearranges the columns so that the smaller ID is always first. That way the previous example of "2 is a duplicate of 1, and 1 is a duplicate of 2" becomes just a repetition of "2 is a duplicate of 1". At that point, you can select distinct values to get a list of IDs to delete from Table A.

Based on your sample data, this query deleted the correct values:

```
WITH Duplicates (ID) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CASE
            WHEN ID1 > ID2 THEN ID1
            WHEN ID2 > ID1 THEN ID2
        END AS Duplicate
    FROM Table_B
)

DELETE
FROM Table_A
WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM Duplicates)
```